# Input- and Output Data Shape Difficulty

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm a Keras beginner. My main problem right now is how to build a model that suits my data.

For the Model itself I'd like to build it so the inputs/outputs are:
**Input Data:** (List that contains) three integers e.g. [24, 63, 122]
**Desired Output:** (A list containg) 32 floating point values in range 0 to 1 e.g. [0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.25, 0, 0.45, 0.1, ... ,0]
I'd like the sum of the 32 floating poits to be 1.

My data format is as follows:
X_Data = [[104, 56, 64], [96, -8, 80], ...
Y_Data = [[0, 0, 0, 1, ... , 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, ...

```
visible = Input(shape=(3,1))
extract1 = LSTM(10)(visible)
output = Dense(32, activation='sigmoid')(extract1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

which sums up to

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3, 1)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 10)                480       
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                352       
=================================================================
Total params: 832
Trainable params: 832
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Executing

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

results in
**InvalidArgumentError:**  required broadcastable shapes

I suspect that I do not quite understand how to pass the right shape information.

Comment: What shapes are your variables `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test`, and `y_test`? Trying the provided code with some random data of shapes `(1000, 3)`, `(1000, 32)`, `(100, 3)`, and `(100, 32)` respectively works without giving an error. In addition, if you want the outputs of your model to sum up to 1 you should use a softmax activation instead of a sigmoid activation.

Comment: @Oxbowerce The shapes are: x_train (1772, 3, 1) / y_train (1772, 2, 32) / x_test (444, 3, 1) / y_test (444, 3, 1)

Comment: Then the issue is likely that the output shape of your model does not align with the shape of your `y_train` dataset. The model expects a matrix of shape `(None, 32)`, whereas you are providing a matrix of shape `(None, 2, 32)`, meaning an extra dimension of two values.  Not sure if it's just a spelling mistake, but in addition the shape of `y_test` has the exact same shape as `x_test` and does not seem to align with `y_train`.

Comment: @Oxbowerce The shape of my trainingdata was different as what I thought. Silly mistake that drove me crazy. The advice of checking the shapes actually helped a lot. Not the model compiles without raising errors. Just like you said! Thank you! Oh and another thank you for the advice of usning the softmax activation function :)

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Also posted my comment as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Then the issue is likely that the output shape of your model does not align with the shape of your `y_train` dataset. The model expects a matrix of shape `(None, 32)`, whereas you are providing a matrix of shape `(None, 2, 32)`, meaning an extra dimension of two values. In addition, if you want the outputs of your model to sum up to 1 you should use a softmax activation instead of a sigmoid activation since a sigmoid activation only bounds values of individual neurons to the 0-1 range.